# Is there a simple & extendable Data Class for ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I've worked with a few of these in the past, but I'm looking for a good, reliable and extensible data class for ASP.NET 3.5, that I can adopt and extend for future projects.

I'm not looking for LinQ, and I don't want anything which won't be a source-code level solution.

Ideally, it also won't be heavy.
Simple.Best Practices.Easy to Implement.Easy to Extend.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you mean by "data class"? What do you want/need it to do for you? Are you looking for something like DataContract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at Mircrosoft's Enterprise library's [Data Access Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309504.aspx)  I have found it useful and it is a building block of [.netTiers](http://nettiers.com/).
[Patterns & Practices Codeplex page](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib)

Answer (score 0):

I wish there were something similar to the DataSet/DataTable/DataRow/etc ADO data classes, but open for extension.  While working with them is sometimes very hard, they make many expensive and complex tasks easy.  Its a tradeoff, definitely.

Comment: You can inherit those classes, they're not sealed or anything. I'm not sure what else you want when you say "open for extension".